# How should I disable the enabled xdebug, not able to download Laravel and use with wampserver?

Tags: php, composer

Command prompt shows it while trying to download and install Laravel.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that XDEBUG is stopping you download this repository, that message is just a informational warning.

The real problem is with the repository you are trying to download.

However, if you want to disable XDEBUG when using the PHP CLI you can do this :-

Edit the php.ini file used by the PHP CLI which is located in `\wamp\bin\php\php{version}\php.ini

Very near the bottom of that file you will find a line like this _version numbers may differ depending on which version of WAMPServer/PHP you are running.

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension ="D:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.45/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.4-vc9.dll"
```

All you need to do is add a comment character (`;`) to that line like this

```
[xdebug]
;zend_extension ="D:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.45/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.4-vc9.dll"
```

Save the file and it will be picked up by the next execution of the `composer.exe`

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

I just ran your example with `XDEBUG` configured using a WAMPServer install V3.0.0 which has PHP5.6.15 and I got this result, suggesting that your issue is not XDEBUG but something else in your `PHP` or `composer' configuration.

```
D:\php_source>composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"

D:\php_source>echo off
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
Changed current directory to D:\wamp\composer
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing symfony/process (v2.8.0)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.0.0)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing symfony/console (v2.8.0)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (1.0.3)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.2.1)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.1.1)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing laravel/installer (v1.2.2)
    Downloading: 100%

symfony/console suggests installing symfony/event-dispatcher ()
symfony/console suggests installing psr/log (For using the console logger)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Comment: still not working...need help with it...urgent

Comment: What bit is not working? The removal of XDEBUG or the downloading of the repositiry

Comment: If this is so urgent, where have you gone. Its been over an hour since I replied to your comment.